# Messed up Kernel parameters, no longer can boot into ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, crash

So I messed things up real bad. It started with trying to get two screens to work.  I was using Ubuntu 16.04 with  Radeon R9 290/390 as my graphics card.  There were apparently some problems with this, and one suggestion was to upgrade to 18.04 and updating the kernals to the newest versions, as some people had success with that.  I did that, but that not only did not fix the problem, everything started moving slower on the computer.  The mouse would lag, etc.

So I started looking into other fixes, including adjusting the kernal parameters.  I set the parameters to

```
radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=1
```

based on this article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#R9_390_series_Poor_Performance_and/or_Instability

That still didn't solve the problem.  I heard that another solution was blacklisting radeon.   I added modprobe.blacklist=radeon to the list of parameters.  In retrospect, I suspect I should have replaced what I had earlier.

After rebooting, now neither Ubuntu or Windows is showing up in the Grub2 options.  After some research I was able to get into Ubuntu from the command line by following this page https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-BOOTING-GRUB-2-LINUX

However, once I get in it crashes immediately and I cannot do anything.

I would change my kernal parameters, but every source tells me to press e on the grub2 menu on ubuntu, but ubuntu isn't an option.  Somehow I need to do this from the command line in grub.  I haven't found a source as to how to do this.  I really need help, I have rendered my computer unusable.

Comment: I guess you edited `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Comment: I used grub customerizer, so yes, but indirectly.

Comment: Have you tried booting into a live session? Do that and type in `sudo su` in the terminal. That should bring up the root terminal. Try changing the parameters there.

If all else fails, you can at least move the files from Ubuntu to another USB drive elsewhere.

Comment: So i need to load Ubuntu onto a USB?  That's tricky at the moment as I can't even get into windows at the moment cause it isn't in the grub list.  I'll have to work out how to get in there from the grub terminal...

Comment: where did you add `modprobe.blacklist=radeon`

Comment: I added it in the grub customizer

Comment: Check [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-BOOTING-GRUB-2-LINUX) on how to boot from grub rescue

Comment: @guillermochamorro I've been using that link, I included it in my initial question.  I can get into Ubuntu with that, but then it crashes because of the kernel parameters.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I didn't realize :p

Comment: @guillermochamorro no problem.  I feel like I'm in a chicken and egg situation.  I need to edit the parameters, which I can do in Ubuntu, but I can't get into Ubuntu because the paraemters are messed up.  And I can't do it from Grub, because it isn't showing up in the grub menu.  I can only do it with booting from console, but I haven't figured out how to fix the parameters from there.

Comment: But if you boot following the link's procedure, you do not add kernel parameters. Whatt do you mean by "crashes"? What kind of error appears?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I added kernel parameters to the grub on boot using Grub customizer.  I believe the parameters I added created a conflict of some sort, the details are in the opening comment.  Basically, sometimes I don't see anything at all but a blank screen.  Sometimes I see my desktop briefly but it then quickly glitches out and goes black, and occasionally I'll see the desktop but it will just freeze and I can't interact with it.

Comment: What I mean is that when you boot fron grub rescue> the command `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic...` should boot the system without any parameters (unless you add them on purpose)

Comment: @guillermochamorro So I'm in the grub console, not grub rescue.  Not sure how to get to rescue, though I assume that doesn't matter if I boot from there.  So perhaps it isn't using the parameters, but it is crashing immediately, so I'm not sure what to do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Boot a live-session und change `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly from your broken system. Remove boot option by the upmost  kernel version. Then try to boot this Kernel. If it works you can remove your boot option in `/etc/default/grub` and update the grub.cfg by running`sudo update-grub`

Comment: So that means I need to get Ubuntu on a USB, right?

Comment: yes or dvd. you should have the installations medium?

Comment: So I don't have it set up on a dvd or a USB right now.  I'm unable to boot into Windows, and I haven't had a chance to do it elsewhere, but I'm still trying things.

Comment: Do you  have at least a windows recovery medium or installations medium?

Comment: I was actually just able to boot into windows manually.  I'm now creating a bootable USB for ubuntu.  Let's see how this goes!

Comment: So I was able to boot up the live session and repair things.  Thanks!